# php codeigniter foreach loop for viewing page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I'm working on this/these problem(s), and there's just a lot going on for recently using codeigniter..

So, I have these specific tables:
**sect_tbl**       -----------   **sub_tbl**

**sect_id** -----------     **sub_code**
2       --------------------ST20
3       --------------------AS13
3       --------------------DA11
1       --------------------PE40
2       --------------------SE10
3       --------------------PE20
4       --------------------RT40

**I made sect_id the foreign key in sub_tbl.**

**the display - a side menu:**

link of sect_ids:
**1**
**2**
**3**
**4**

I want to make it so, that if I click the link of sect_id 3, I'll be redirected to a new page with its corresponding set of sub_code --  "AS13, DA11, PE20" as seen in the table above.

**Expected outcome is something like this:**

**sub_code** 
(in sect_id-3)

### |   AS13    |

### |   DA11    |

### |   PE20    |

**Model:** **(most definitely not right )**

```
 function fetch_view($data){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT a.sub_code, a.sub_name, a.sect_id, 
        b.block_name,       b.year_level FROM subject as a JOIN section as b 
         WHERE a.sect_id = b.sect_id ");
       return $query->result();
       }
```

**Controller:**

```
 $data["subjects"] = $this->view_model->fetch_view($this->session-
    userdata('user_id'));
```

**view:** (this lacking since I cant get around much further with foreach loop yet )

```
    <?php
       foreach ($subjects as $row) {
    ?>

    <a href=""> <?php echo $row->year_level.$row->block_name; ?></a>

   <?php
     }
    ?>
```

-> I tried working my way with href to redirect me and then be able to view it dynamically but it backfired. Thanks a lot to those who could spare their time to share solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you say you want all sub codes where sect ID = 3

```
$sect_id = 3;
```

I simplified your query, but the main problem was that you had no use of "on x = y" for your join

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT 
        sec.year_level,
        sec.block_name,
        sub.sub_code,  
    FROM section as sec
    JOIN subject as sub
    ON sec.sect_id = sub.sect_id 
    WHERE sec.sect_id = ?
", [ $sect_id ] );

if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    return $query->result();

return [];
```

Then, because I don't have your actual table schemas, I couldn't suggest if your view is correct, but in general, something like this should work:

```
$this->load->helper('url');

foreach( $subjects as $row )
{
    echo anchor( 'subs/show/' . $row->sub_code, $row->year_level . $row->block_name );
}
```

Also, as a side note, try to always follow a code style with proper indentation. It makes things that are wrong stand out and easier to fix.

Comment: thanks for answering though what solved my problem was the ff:    

`$sect_id = $this->uri->segment(3); 

       if (isset($sect_id) && !empty($sect_id)) {
          //query & result here            
    }`